# expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction while using scope resolution with macro

Tags: c++

Unable to find why compiler is unable to interpret scope resolution operator
properly when we use with macro. Could someone explain the reason?

#### File1.cpp

```
#define MACRO_DEF(entryType, ptr) \
    ptr = new entryType (); \
```

#### File2.cpp

```
Class A {
    class B {
    };
    class C {
    };
};
```

#### File3.cpp

```
Class D {
    A::B* obj;
    MACRO_DEF(A::B, obj); /* getting below error in first argument. */
};
```

#### Error mesage:

```
    error: 
    error: expected '(' for function-style cast or type construction
    MACRO_DEF(A::B, obj)
              ~~~~^
```

Comment: The macro is defined in File1.cpp, so it's not visible in File3.cpp

Comment: Neither are `A` or `B` visible in file3.cpp, so I suspect this might be a case of 'not the real code'.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Once I clean up your code, it compiles fine for me. See it live on [Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d5ff0004a91a7a5). What compiler and version are you using? Can you modify the code I linked to in order to demonstrate your error?

Comment: @metal I'd rather see the code modified in this question than on an external web site.

Comment: @john: It's a commonly used online compiler that has the added benefit of showing that the code actually works. Cleanup included putting it all in one file (probably the cause of the OP's problems), fixing capitalization of `Class`, adding `public:` to `C`, and converting `D` to `main()`.

Comment: @dave But then `Class A` (by the way, not `class` with small `c`?) defined in `File2.cpp` won't be visible in `File3.cpp`, either. It seems a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is required.

Comment: Ankush: PS, macros are generally frowned upon and should be avoided. See, for instance, [this C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/misc-technical-issues#macros-with-if).

Comment: @metal I've no problem with you posting links to online compilers, but encouraging the OP to move the discussion off site seems wrong. If the OP has corrections to make to the posted code they should be made here.

Comment: @john: Totally agree. The OP should update this post to be a minimum, reproducible example. I was just offering my modified and building source as a possible way to get there.